# how to store key-pair values

Tags: solidity, contract-development

Is there any way to store the values like we store in Python using a dictionary?
for eg: there are 5 states and a single address. I want to store these states as

```
my_pair = {'state_one id': 'address ','state_two id': 'address'}
```

Note: Address remains the same only the state_id is changing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [mappings](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/develop/types.html#mappings). You declare the key type and the value type as such

`mapping(uint => address) my_pair;
my_pair[0] = 0x123
address currentState = my_pair[0];`

Now currentState holds 0x123.

Comment: Note: You should be aware that the key is not stored in the mapping.